# How can I uninstall demo templates of User module (Solspace)?

Tags: solspace-user

I have installed the demo templates just to have a look at each template and what it delivers at the frontend.

But for my site, I do not want all these pages to be available to the user. There seems to be no option of uninstalling these demo templates. I uninstalled the user module and reinstalled it ( I didn't installed the demo templates again) but the demo templates are still showing up those user pages.

Any suggestions welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just delete them

Comment: Yes that a way, or better if I could keep them and let only the admin see those pages. Is there a way for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as Jim recommended. You can just delete them. If you want to keep them just move them to a different template group and set those templates to redirect to 404 for everyone. Only superadmins will be able to view them after that. For reference (EE 2 docs):

https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/cp/design/templates/template_preferences_manager.html#modify-preferences-and-access

Comment: Or you can add in the header:
{if group_id != "1"}
{redirect="404"}
{/if}